The metric and Ricci tensors of 3D geometry with isometry of a Cylinder
I'm studying 3D Riemannian geometries with (what I believe can be said to be) the isometry of a cylinder - the manifold is invariant under:

Rotation around the third axis (with an arbitrary angle)
Reflection symmetry with-respect-to any plane that includes the third axis
Reflection with-respect-to the xy-plane.

Edit: I initially wrote this question referring to isometry of a spheroid (an ellipsoid with two axes with the same length). However I think that a spheroid is diffemorphic to a sphere, and it's not what I'm looking for.
My first question: Is there any terminology of point group symmetry that can help me with this kind of geometry? I'm weak on point group symmetry. I tried searching via google in different ways and found nothing indicative...
So far I came to the following conclusions, when using the conventional cylindrical coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$:
(1) Any rank (0,2)-tensor or (2,0)-tensor that are symmetric, e.g. $S_{m n}=S_{n m}$, that are invariant to the isometry must have the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
U & 0 & Q \\
0 & U \cdot r^2 & 0 \\
Q & 0 & V \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$U(r,\theta,z) = U(r,\theta,-z)$
$V(r,\theta,z) = V(r,\theta,-z)$
$Q(r,\theta,z) = -Q(r,\theta,-z)$
$\partial_{\theta}U = \partial_{\theta}V = \partial_{\theta}Q = 0$

(2) the metric tensor should have the form
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
e^{2u} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & e^{2u} \cdot r^2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & e^{2v} \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$u(r,\theta,z)=v(r,\theta,-z)$
$u(r,\theta,z)=v(r,\theta,-z)$
$\partial_{\theta}u = \partial_{\theta}v = 0$

I'm currently stuck after I compute the components of the Ricci tensor. I used Cadabra package for python and got expressions in the form:

$R_{r r}=e^{2(u-v)} \cdot F(u,v) + \partial_r{u} \cdot \partial_r{v} - \partial_r{\partial_r(u+v)} - 2(\partial_r{u})^2 -r^{-1}\partial_r{u}$
$R_{\theta \theta}=r^2 [e^{2(u-v)} \cdot F(u,v) - (\partial_r{u} \cdot \partial_r{v} + \partial_r{\partial_r{u}} + r^{-1}\partial_r(u+v))]$

$F(u,v)$ also includes partial-derivatives of u and v with-respect-to the z coordinate, and there are other non-vanishing components ($R_{z z}$ and $R_{r z}=R_{z r}$) but they are less important at the moment.
Since the Ricci tensor should be invariant under the isometry, then its form should be as written above and therefore I reach the conclusion that the functions $u(r,z)$ and $v(r,z)$ must also fulfill
$$0=\partial_r{u} \cdot \partial_r{v} - \partial_r{\partial_r(u+v)} - 2(\partial_r{u})^2 -r^{-1}\partial_r{u} + \partial_r{u} \cdot \partial_r{v} + \partial_r{\partial_r{u}} + r^{-1}\partial_r(u+v)$$
$$2\partial_r(v-u) \cdot \partial_r{u} = r\partial_r(r^{-1} \partial_r{v})$$
My second question: Does this look like a reasonable constraint on the components of the metric tensor with the cylinder-like isometry?
